# Google page speed returning object rather than the speed

Tags: php

this is my controller.i am trying to integrate the google page speed to my laravel project.

```
class TestController extends Controller
{
    public function pagespeed()
    {
        $pageSpeed = new \PageSpeed\Insights\Service();
        $pagespeed = $pageSpeed->getResults('http://www.thesecretlab.nl');
        return $pagespeed;
    }
}
```

the output is a whole array.I wanted to get the speed value?

Comment: [Accessing array elements with square bracket syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.accessing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could replace:

```
return $pagespeed;
```

By:

```
return $pagespeed['ruleGroups']['SPEED']['score'];
```

Comment: it keeps complaining that : ['ruleGroups']['SPEED']['score'] are undfined index.